Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key')
I want to test the randomness about Swithboard on Solana devent. I followed the tutorial(https://docs.switchboard.xyz/docs/switchboard/switchboard-randomness/on-solana-svm-networks), but get an error when running to the commit ix step.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key')
      at Queue.<anonymous> (node_modules/@switchboard-xyz/on-demand/src/accounts/queue.ts:788:19)
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at fulfilled (node_modules/@switchboard-xyz/on-demand/dist/cjs/accounts/queue.js:38:58)

Test code:
  it("swith board VRF", async () => {
    const { keypair, connection, provider, wallet } =
      await AnchorUtils.loadEnv();
    const payer = wallet.payer;
    console.log("payer", payer.publicKey.toString());

    // Switchboard sbQueue fixed
    const sbQueue = new PublicKey(
      "EYiAmGSdsQTuCw413V5BzaruWuCCSDgTPtBGvLkXHbe7"
    );
    const sbProgramId = ON_DEMAND_DEVNET_PID;
    console.log("sbProgramId", sbProgramId.toString());

    const sbIdl = await anchor.Program.fetchIdl(sbProgramId, provider);
    const sbProgram = new anchor.Program(sbIdl!, provider);
    console.log("sbProgramId", sbProgram.programId.toString());

    const queueAccount = new Queue(sbProgram, sbQueue);

    console.log("queueAccount1", queueAccount.pubkey.toString());

    // let queueAccout2 = await getDefaultDevnetQueue();
    // console.log("queueAccount2", queueAccout2.pubkey.toString());

    // create randomness
    const rngKp = Keypair.generate();
    console.log("rngKp", rngKp.publicKey.toString());

    const [randomness, randomnessCreateIx] = await Randomness.create(
      sbProgram,
      rngKp,
      sbQueue
    );
    console.log("randomness", randomness.pubkey.toString());

    let createRandomnessTransaction = new Transaction().add(randomnessCreateIx);
    console.log("createRandomnessTransaction", createRandomnessTransaction);

    await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      provider.connection,
      createRandomnessTransaction,
      [payer, rngKp]
    );

    console.log("start commitIx");
    console.log("sbQueue", sbQueue.toString());
    const commitIx = await randomness.commitIx(sbQueue); // problem here
    console.log("commitIx", commitIx.programId.toString());

    const revealIx = await randomness.revealIx();
    console.log("revealIx", revealIx.programId.toString());

    let commitAndRevealtransaction = new Transaction()
      .add(commitIx)
      .add(revealIx);
    console.log("commitAndRevealtransaction", commitAndRevealtransaction);

    await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      provider.connection,
      commitAndRevealtransaction,
      [user]
    );

    let mint = new PublicKey(process.env.NFT_MINT);
    console.log("mint", mint.toString());

    const [warriorCardVariantPDA] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from("warrior_card_variant"), mint.toBuffer()],
      program.programId
    );
    console.log("warriorCardVariantPDA", warriorCardVariantPDA.toString());

    console.log("start warriorCardCrossChain");

    let warriorCardCrossChainTx = await program.methods
      .warriorCardCrossChain()
      .accounts({
        randomnessAccountData: randomness.pubkey,
        warriorCardVariant: warriorCardVariantPDA,
        mint: mint,
        payer: user,
      })
      .signers([user])
      .rpc();
    console.log("warriorCardCrossChainTx", warriorCardCrossChainTx);

    let warriorCardVariantInfo = program.account.warriorCardVariant.fetch(
      warriorCardVariantPDA
    );

    console.log(
      "warriorCardVariantInfo",
      JSON.stringify(warriorCardVariantInfo, null, 2)
    );
  });

